# TryGetFormCredentials returns null on cross-domain request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, cors, owin

I've set up OAuth authentication in a project that uses WebAPI, and I had it working 100% fine.

Then I moved the front end app into a separate project in the solution. So now when I run the app, it's obviously on a different url (localhost:64049) to the API & Authentication Server (which are in the same project, server from localhost:63265).

To get CORS working, I believe I need to add this line to `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`

```
context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });
```

However, when I run it, the `TryGetFormCredentials` in `ValidateClientAuthentication` is not returning the clientId.

If I send the request from Fiddler/Postman, it still works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by enabling CORS on the app in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

I had to remove the other Response Headers, though.